Key fob frequency filter design
I was hooked by this flipper zero reel. This is the filter they showcased to pass the key fob signal:

Unfortunately, the inductor is not very clear, and I want to seek help with the design, so I can try it. With my limited knowledge of filters, I tried to figure out the inductance using the resonance formula, and it is 1.35 pH which is very small.
Am I doing something wrong here? And is there a better design? Also, what is the purpose of the diode in the circuit?

For broadband operation the coil is just a choke, no need to resonate anything. It can be replaced with a second diode in a voltage doubler configuration. With no DC path for the diode, the circuit is incomplete. Put a higher value shunt resistor (e.g. 10...100k) and shunt capacitor (e.g. 1nF) for filtering purposes between the diode and the DC blocking capacitor.

This is just a diode detector. The exact inductor value is unknown, even to the authors of that video. You will have to try until you see signal at the output.
Is it a good circuit? No. Is the point that you can receive a strong signal (such of from a keyfob that was nearly rubbed against the audio amplifier) with even the least specific tools? Yes.
This is not a proper frequency filter! All it does is really have higher impedance to RF than the diode and capacitor.
It does not serve to isolate the 433 MHz channel the key fob uses. Try with a 900 MHz fob next, it should work just as well (or badly), roughly.
This all only works because the fob uses OOK, on-off keying; that means it sends energy to signal a "1" and nothing to signal a "0". That's the most basic radio modulation, and it's used by fewer and fewer devices (ancient key fobs and ancient garage door openers are pretty much the two device classes I can come up with). It's mathematically bad, because with the same transmit power you can build something that has lower error probability (or you can transmit with less power, i.e., with less usage of battery for the same performance) if you don't use OOK, but something different.
OOK can, due to only the power mattering, be received without proper filtering, if there's nothing stronger in the air. You just measure how much power there is – exactly what a rectifier diode does.
OOK is the typical example of what us communications engineers see being investigated by computer security ("infosec") people. Why? Some say it's because you need no theoretical background in communications to "hack" on it. It's a bit mean, but it has become kind of an idiom to my peers that when someone finds an OOK device and decodes it and then makes a blog post / twitter article / youtube video about their RF hacking prowress, we call it "infosec RF", instead of "communications engineering".

can I casually plug in a cut earphone and pick up the signals ?

Good answer. A suggestion: Your answer would be improved if you defined your acronyms. OOK is On-Off keying

1.35 pH is a too-small guess for inductance.
Once again, a video has suggested, “hey, this is so easy”. To optimize this, coil inductance (likely in the hundred nanohenry ballpark) resonates with antenna capacitance, plus zero-bias diode capacitance at the key-fob's transmitted frequency.
For example, a 315 MHz key-fob would require a resonating capacitance of about 2.55 pF to match a 100 nH coil inductance.
Optimizing this balance of capacitance with inductance takes some experimentation. A small coil - even if not resonated by a capacitance - will couple to a key-fob's antenna if placed close enough.
The diode acts as an amplitude detector. A 1N34A germanium diode is suggested — a good choice. A small Schottky diode might work too.
